# Antiderivative of $(\sin^2 x − \sin^3x)^2\cos x$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone show me how to antidifferentiate $(\sin^2 x − \sin^3x)^2\cos x$ step by step? I'm a bit confused on what to do.

Comment: Try substituting $u=\sin x, du = \cos x dx$. This reduces the integrand to a polynomial.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can observe that the integrand has a function and its derivative, try a $u$-substitution:

$$u = \sin x \quad \mathrm du = \cos x \,\mathrm dx$$

And once you substitute this in, you get:

$$\require{cancel} \int \left(\sin^2 x - \sin^3x\right)^2\cos x \,\mathrm dx = \int \left(u^2-u^3\right)^2\cancel{\cos x} {\mathrm du \over \cancel{\cos x}}$$

You can then expand the polynomial and integrate easily.

Comment: The second part of this questions is 'If f : R → R is odd, then calculate $\int_-a^a f(x) \,dx=0$ for any positive number a', would I just sub in any postive number a into the equation?

Comment: @Okie If a function is odd, meaning it has symmetry wrt the origin, then $\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is always $0$.

Comment: but when it says 'to calculate', do i just find what a could be when it equals to 0?

Comment: @Okie No, for any constant $a$, the definite integral of an odd function $f(x)$ from $-a$ to $a$ is $0$. There's nothing really to calculate, but to realize that any odd function will have origin symmetry which has the effect of $-\int_{-a}^0 f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$u = \sin x$$
$$\mathrm du = \cos x$$

$$(\sin^2x-\sin^3x)^2\cos x \,\mathrm dx = (u^2 - u^3)^2\mathrm du $$

$$\int (u^4 - 2u^5 + u^6)\,\mathrm du =  \frac15 u^5 - \frac13u^6+\frac17u^7 = \frac15 \sin^5x - \frac13\sin^6x+\frac17\sin^7x + C$$